# Adding a component to html table via Javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, function, cell

I have a 3rd party component that I need to add to a menu bar on our web page.  The menu bar is an html table with one row of cell's, each cell is a link and I need to add another cell that contains this component.  I have been given a Javascript api from the developer of the component. I can easily add another cell to the menu bar, but how do I add this component to the table.  Obviously I am not an experienced html/Javascript developer so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: And the reason you are not asking this to the anonymous 3rd party component maker?

Comment: The 3rd party's development group has not been responsive and I am under a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to let the component do its stuff when a visitor clicks on this new cell? In case of yes, your html should look basically like this:

```
<td onclick="component.doStuff()">Click me</td>
```

However, my answer will get downvoted, because it is bad practice. So here's another approach:

```
<td id="myCell">Click me</td> 
<script>
  document.getElementByID("myCell").onclick = component.doStuff;
</script>
```

The latter gives you the possibility to place the code where ever your (complex) framework it requires.

Comment: No. I need to know if I can actually load this component into a table cell when the menu bar/table is rendered.  I don't want to load the component as a response to an event handler.

Comment: Hmm, so you want to show the component instead of a menu item? Is it Flash?

Comment: Yes... as odd as this all sounds.  I am not in the position to make design decisions.  No, it is not Flash.

Comment: Sounds good. So, some HTML tags have to find their way between <td> and </td>. Will the component do this job? Or is there any kind of instruction?